# Python Barplot ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I try to plot a simple barplot in Python, but when I run the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']
y=[47, 23, 27,  0, 82,  7, 46, 92, 36, 76]
plt.bar(x,y)
plt.xlabel('Categories')
plt.ylabel("Values")
plt.title('Categories Bar Plot')
plt.show()
```

I get an error message:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'A'
```

I don't know why this does not work, especially because it's an exact copy of an example from a website which should work.

Comment: This works fine with the current version of matplotlib. I'm voting to close this as not reproducible.

Answer (score 2):

Which pandas/matplotlib versions are you using? Have you made sure to use a clean environment?

You code works fine for me.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']
y=[47, 23, 27,  0, 82,  7, 46, 92, 36, 76]
plt.bar(x,y)
plt.xlabel('Categories')
plt.ylabel("Values")
plt.title('Categories Bar Plot')
plt.show()
```

output:

[image: bar plot]

Comment: OK thanks a lot, I will try to shut down and restart everything

Comment: the error is quite strange since "plotting" letters should work (try `plt.bar(x,x)`), thus my question on matplotlib's version

Comment: It was because I have to use matplotlib 1.5.1, down under I posted my workaround

Comment: Thanks for providing a feedback to the community ;)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, I use matplotlib 1.5.1 and I can't upgrade it because of reasons I can't write here.
But I wrote a workaround I wanted to share with the community:

```
x1=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J']
N=0
x2=[]
for i in range(len(x1)):
    x2.append(N)
    N+=1
y=[47, 23, 27,  0, 82,  7, 46, 92, 36, 76]
plt.bar(x2,y)
plt.xlabel('Categories')
plt.ylabel("Values")
plt.title('Categories Bar Plot')
plt.xticks(np.arange(0.5, len(x2)+0.5), list(x1), rotation=90, size = '10')
plt.show()
```